# using session in a client server wcf application

Tags: c#, wcf, session, client

I have a wpf application with wcf services. All service calls are made through a proxy. This is a server client application, meaning you would typically have one server and several clients. My issue is that I need to be able to track each user that logs in on the server side of the application. I have considered using a static class and decorating the needed property with [ThreadStatic]. This property on the static class is set during log-in in the authenticated service. The problem is that the values on the property keeps getting set to null when other clients log in. I can not find a solution for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the ServiceBehaviour InstanceContextMode to Single, but then all clients will be working on the same instance... I'm facing the same issue, ...